# Spring Stream Kafka re-reads all messages

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Using Spring cloud stream version Brooklyn.SR1 with spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka in my spring-boot application. I'm getting an undesirable situation each time my application is restarted my application re reads all of the messages that are persisted on the Kafka bus. I set the properties `consumer.resetOffsets = true` and `consumer.startOffset = true`. At first it looked like those properties resolved the situation but i was able to reproduce it. surly I'm doing something wrong

Comment: How is this question related tag `apache-kafka-streams`?

Comment: spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.configuration.auto.offset.reset= latests ?

Answer (score 0):

> spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings..consumer.startOffset =
>   latest

worked for me.